# Outlook 2010 addin Access is denied

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Im trying to create an outlook 2010 addin. I just created the standard project, when trying to run it i get the following error...

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

******* *Exception Text* *********
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager..ctor(Uri deploymentSource, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isConfirmed, DownloadOptions downloadOptions, AsyncOperation optionalAsyncOp)
   at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager..ctor(Uri deploymentManifest, Boolean launchInHostProcess)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.IPHMProxy..ctor(Uri uri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.get_Proxy()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have some problem in your Local Settings folder. Try deleting it, reboot and it will be recreated. That's how I've solved a few access denied errors when dealing with QlickOnce.

The Local Settings-folder is hidden default. It's found here on Windows 7 (and Vista):

```
C:\Users\{user name}\AppData\Local
```

And here on Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{user name}\AppData\Local
```

Comment: Be aware that this **will** remove **any** appliaction settings that are stored there. I would not advise this unless you backup everything in there first.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on one of my team mate's machine after installing setup of word addin. I created installer using Installshield's limited edition. The issue was in registry entry. Path in Manifest entry was having "**file:///**" at start which was somehow causing error.

First I manually changed path in manifest registry (at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\YourAddin\Manifest) from "**file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/...../My.vsto**" to "**C:/Program Files (x86)/...../My.vsto**" and it worked. Then I fixed that in my setup project too.

Hope this helps somene.

Comment: finally got the actual culprit....it was a local settings file which got corrupted (not sure how and why) so i had to delete that file (C:\Users\**<user>**\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat). Got clue from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ef690458-22bc-4d72-a36c-773c1cc6fa15/clickonce-application-cannot-be-started-help?forum=winformssetup